# Get last inserted row's complex primary key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Consider the following table, completely random for the example

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`,`id2`,`id3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to insert and get the unique identifier for the inserted row, which would be the complex primary key. If I had a single column primary key I would use `PDO::lastInsertId`, but if I use it in this case I get result `string(1) "0"` for statement `INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'test')`. Is there any way I could get the primary key columns of a complex key after insert? In this particular case from the statement above I need to get `array(1, 1, 1)`

Comment: The composite key cannot be generated by the database, so the values must be provided by your INSERT query. That raises the question, why to retrieve the key when the values are already known to your script?

Comment: @syck That's a good question but the explanation is not easy. I'm making a code generator and it's a little bit sophisticated (for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mySQL is able to return you the last inserted key only if the field is generated by the system, otherwise, it will not be possible to retrieve the last saved data with a function.

You could go for a generated identifier and retrieve every key with a second select, but I'm not sure the performance will suit your expectations. Sorry.